# Double scroll bar in dialog

Tags: css, angular, dialog

I fixed the height of the Bootstrap dialog, but for some reason a double scroll bar appeared, but I just needed to try overflow: hidden, but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. The problem comes when I select a check box and the dialog jumps down since a longer part of the dialog comes in, I can't paste many codes because the components of the dialog are made up of several components.

So far I have done css formatting:

```
  body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  .dialog-layout-modal-body {
    min-height: 662px;
    max-height: 700px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

And the parent CSS code:

```
body {
  overlfow: hidden;
}
```

Is there some bootstrap or css or any solution how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you thought of marking as overflow: hidden !important;

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not help

Answer (score 0):

One is from `browser` scroll and another is from the `dialog`. Check if the Parent section has css property as 'overflow:auto;` which will cause this issue.

OR

you can do something like this for `body` tag.

```
body{
  width:100%;
  overflow-x:hidden; // hides bottom scroll
  overflow-y:hidden; // hides vertical scroll
  }
```

Comment: I tried this solution too, but unfortunately the error is the same @Manjuboys

Comment: can you take out that `min-height`? and let me know, I would appreciate if you share CSS for both modal and parent page.

Comment: I need the minimum height to fit the visualization and I passed the CSS code to the parent

Comment: I am happy to help you if you share what css you have used apart from the code you shared.

Comment: body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  .dialog-layout-modal-body {
    min-height: 662px;
    max-height: 700px;
    overflow: auto;
  }

And add the parent component to:

body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

Comment: Didn't you mean that?

Comment: what is the `height` of body? and I need to see complete code not in comment section, if it is possible to add it in your post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209913/discussion-between-manjuboyz-and-vargaadam).